# How to get the Angular.json for my NX Workspace?

Tags: angular, npm, web-applications, setup-project

I want to create a new Angular web app inside my empty NX Workspace, so I can later build it for iOS and Android with Capacitor. I already created the nx monorepo. Then I created a new Angular application with the command `nx g @nrwl/angular:app appName`. The web app can successfully be started with `nx serve appName`. But to build this app from the NX Workspace i need an Angular.json file. How can I get this file to build my web app?

Answer (score 3):

the nx workspace provide project.json instead of angular.json

--> if you want to add any style or script project.json instead of angular.json

Comment: But there is no project.json inside of my nx workspace

Answer (score 0):

you don't need angular.json to build the app. You can build it with nx build `project-name`